# regex - extract domain name and TLD

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract domain name and TLD (if it exists) from a string.

For "testing.co.uk" I want to have an array with values: ("testing", "co.uk")

For "-testing.c" I want to have an array with a value: ("testing")

For "test-ing.co.uk.com" I want to have an array with values ("test-ing","co.uk")

Rules are simple:

- first and last character of the domain name can't be "-"
- TLD has to have at least two characters
- TLD part may have one dot character "." but only if it's followed by at least two letters

I have this:

- `(\w[-\w]*\w)` - First part that extracts the domain name (Working)
- `\.(\w{2,}(\.?\w{2,})?)` - get the TLD (not working)

Answer (score 4):

If we can make the assumption that the TLD is at most 2 subsections long, at the end of the string (the last subsection is always part of the TLD) and that the middle subsection is at between 2 and 3 chars long. That there is at least one subsection in the string that is not the TLD then the following should match most cases. Your assumption about domains requiring all alphanumeric with dashes in the middle is correct. Each segment can only be 63 chars long.

```
^((?:www\.)?(?:\w[-\w]{0-61}\w|\w)(?:\.\w[-\w]{0-61}\w|\w)*?)\.((?:\w{2-3}\.)?\w+))$
```

To explain:

`(?:   )` means a non-capturing match, you can use +, *, ? on it but it won't be returned in your answer

`^` and `$` match the start and end of the string respectively

`{n-m}` is like * or + but matches a specific number of chars

`*?` means match 0 or more matches, but is non-greedy so matches the least number of times required for a valid match. It means that subsections that could potentially be matched by either side of the regexp will go into the TLD.

`(?:www\.)?` this is a bugfix for short domain names such as www.un.org

`(?:\w[-\w]{0-61}\w|\w)` ensures that there is at least one subsection in the domain part and that each section is at max 63 chars (61+2=63). Subsection is captured by the outside brackets. The |\w bit at the end solves for the edge case of one letter domain names such as x.org and i.net.

`(?:\.\w[-\w]{0-61}\w)*?|\w)` needs to be repeated as the first subsection cannot start with a dot. Zero or more of these are required, but make it a non-greedy search.

`((?:\w{2-3}\.)?\w+)` matches the TLD according to the rules above. The last subsection is always part of the TLD. The rules on what constitutes a second level TLD are more fuzzy

This regexp is not completely foolproof, as there are a few exceptions that violate the above rules. www.un.com is one example of a one segment TLD with a short domain name. gmp.police.uk (Greater Manchester Police) is an example of another domain where the TLD (police.uk) will not be properly matched (it will match as uk).

I have expanded the length of TLD segments to {2-4} as we need to include domains such as .info and .mod.uk. I have reduced the length of the second TLD segment to {2-3} in order to reduce the number of mismatches on four letter domain names, not much we can do about two or three letter domain names, but they will only be mismatched if the domain also contains a subdomain such as blog.cat.com

Here is a list of some of the TLDs already in use, which might highlight some of the edge cases. I don't think there are any  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.uk

Comment: Thanks, your post brought me a lot closer to what I need.

Looks like \w includes underscore character "_" that can't be used in domain names or TLDs.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are marking this question as correct since it clearly dosn't work: http://rubular.com/r/z4aD5U9I8H I appriciate the effort and it did lead me to my own answer that handles the same test a lot better. Until someone posts something that works, this question will be answerless

Answer (score 0):

A regex is - at best - a half-solution to the problem, for cases where some inaccuracy is acceptable but more complex approaches can't be used.

If you want more accuracy, you probably want to use a solution which incorporates the Public Suffix List: https://publicsuffix.org/. I see libraries in a number of languages which use this, like `tldextract` in Python, or `psl` in js.

For a moment I considered whether it would be possible to convert that list into a regex, but the file is currently over 14,000 lines long, including comments and whitespace. So that's a recipe for an inefficient and difficult to maintain regex.

Answer (score -7):

After stripping `http://` and `https://` from the url, this works for me:

```
(?:www\.)?((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63}(?<!-))\.?((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})?)
```

I check one url at a time and if it returns two matches I consider it valid (since I don't have regex skills to do the same check there).

Try it out here: http://rubular.com/r/CXmWlSuikP

Comment: Way to take @Jamie McGuigan's suggestion, improve on it, submit it and mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: @tntu, What part of that doesn't work? Just wondering because I'm about to do something similar.

Comment: @achinda99 i don't recall exactly the url i tested. just try a few and you well notice it easy as I did not have a hard time discovering it did not work.

Comment: @budidino Doesn't work for urls that end up with .co.uk and other similar TLDs.

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/CXmWlSuikP - but I see there is a problem as it continues fetching stuff after it finds the data I need :/

Comment: Feel free to post a better solution. This one worked for me as I only grab the first regex result and present it to the user. Check it out live here: http://rubular.com/r/kE67U61j4U