# How to get the only suffix part of domain?

Tags: php, regex, arrays

Please consider the below list of domains suffix:

```
COM .CO .INFO .NET .ORG .US .CA .MOBI .BIZ .ME .CC .NAME .TV .WS .DE .AM .FM .BZ .COM.BZ .NET.BZ .ES .ASIA .SE .XXX
```

I need to extract the only suffix part from above domains list. For example, If I have 'www.google.com', 'www.backforgood.us', 'www.birdslisten.org'... and etc, the only part I need are 'com', 'us', 'org'?

I need to cover all the domain suffix mentioned in above list. Is it possible with single regex? Or any other good solution will be helpful? Thanks

Comment: What if `www.example.co.in` comes.You want .in or `.co.in`

Comment: the regex part is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267389/regex-extract-domain-name-and-tld

Comment: @User016, I want '.co.in', the complete suffix part. As my list contains 'COM.BZ'

Comment: @IrfanDayan see my updated answer you will have your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `.co.in` and `.co.uk` suffix using below code.

**Example**

```
$host = 'http://www.google.co.in';
//$host = 'http://www.google.co.uk';
preg_match('/(.*?)((\.co)?.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $host, $m);
echo $ext = isset($m[2]) ? $m[2]: '';
```

code is tested for `.co.in` and `.co.uk`

And for `.com.biz` you need to alter regular expression a bit.

```
$host = 'http://www.google.com.biz';
preg_match('/(.*?)((\.co[a-zA-Z])?.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $host, $m);
echo $ext = isset($m[2]) ? $m[2]: '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this if you want the last part of the domain

```
$name = 'www.birdslisten.org';
$array = explode(".", $name);
end($array);
$suffix = current($array);
echo $suffix;
```

Comment: @DevangRathod, Yes It should include '.co.in'. I need the complete suffix part of domain. As my list contains 'COM.BZ'

Comment: @User016 You already said yourself that what about .co.in and you are posting answer without checking ?