# Perl Regex E-Mail TLD

Tags: regex, perl, email, tld

i have this code:

```
    if ( $Mail =~ /$Tld{$_}/ ) {
        $TldFound = 1;      
    }
```

The variable $Mail has for example the info "mail@mail.com". The variable $Tld has the info ".com". How can i cut the variable $Mail that only the tld .com will remain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex - extract domain name and TLD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267389/regex-extract-domain-name-and-tld)

Comment: You don't have a specific problem other than your lack of knowledge of Perl. You shouldn't learn the language incrementally by relying on the good will of people on Stack Overflow, and I believe what you need is a [Perl tutorial](https://www.perl.org/learn.html)

Comment: You could do a hacky solution with `@.*\.(.*)` This would store everything after the last `.` into `$1` or `\1`. However for foreign domains this wouldn't work or rather you'd also want the second level domain I suspect (e.g. co.uk).

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Email::Address](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Address) to parse email addresses.

To be able to extract a TLD with certainty requires a list of what you consider to be TLDs. For example, do `.co.uk`, or `.com.tr` count? Or, do you just want the last string of non-dot characters?

If you restrict your attention to 2 - 3 character TLDs such as `.co`, `.com`, `.io`, `.net`, `.org`, `.us` etc, you can do `my ($tld) = ($email =~ /[.] ([a-z]{2,3}) \z/x);` and then check with `if ($tld and ($tld eq 'com')) { ... }` etc, but you really want a good list of acceptable strings that can be TLDs: [Net::Domain::TLD](http://p3rl.org/Net::Domain::TLD), [Mozilla::PublicSuffix](http://p3rl.org/Mozilla::PublicSuffix).

Comment: While I agree with your first sentence, your answer *creates* needless complexity not required by the original question. Your approach would require an exhaustive list of TLDs, which is overkill for this particular problem.

Comment: I've mostly found that when people say "not required", they end up spending their weekends and holidays fighting the fires that later causes. You don't need an exhaustive list: just one comprehensive enough for the problem. Even then, what's that? Five minutes of googling?

Answer (score -2):

### Naive Regex Solutions

The following solutions will solve your problem as posted, but are not intended to address every possible edge case. Parsing email addresses in a comprehensive way is non-trivial, and requires a parser such as [Email::Address](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Address) if you want to handle the full complexity of the RFCs.

#### Printing Your TLD from a String

Since you already know the string you want to print on success (e.g. ".com"), you don't actually need the *result* of your regular expression match; you can print the string stored in *$Tld* when the match is true using a post-statement condition. For example:

```
$Mail = 'mail@mail.com';
$Tld  = '.com';

print "$Tld\n" if $Mail =~ /${Tld}$/;
```

This will correctly print:

> .com

#### Printing the Match

If you really want the full match, there are a number of ways to do it. One way would be to use the special *$&* variable:

```
$Mail = 'mail@mail.com';
$Tld  = '.com';

if ($Mail =~ /${Tld}$/) {
    print "$&\n";
}
```

This will also correctly print:

> .com

### Partitioning the String

All of the previous examples will solve your problem as posted, but the best *generic* solution short of a parser is really to partition the TLD, and treat the last segment of the domain as an unvalidated TLD. Ruby has the super-handy [String#rpartition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-rpartition) method, but I'm unaware of a similar function in Perl. However, you can use an anchored match to accomplish much the same thing. For example:

```
$Mail = 'mail@mail.com';

$Mail =~ /(\.[[:alpha:]]+)$/;
print "$1\n";
```

If you need to validate the TLD against an expected value such as `.com`, you can compare it to a string or variable. For example:

```
$Mail = 'mail@mail.com';
$Tld  = '.com';

$Mail =~ /(\.[[:alpha:]]+)$/;
print "$1\n" if $1 eq $Tld
```

Comment: This answer is so wrong in so many ways ... First, what do you think `$Mail` contains after `$Mail = "mail@mail.com"`? Second, do you realize `.` is special in a regex pattern? Third, what if `$Mail` contains `acommander@example.org`? What is the point of posting stuff like this?

Comment: @SinanÜnür Thank you for your rant, and for publicly displaying your lack of social skills on Stack Overflow. The answer works, provides self-contained examples, and will solve the OP's *posted problem*, and is not intended to solve every imaginable edge case. However, the answer has been updated to anchor the regex since I agree that it `/.com/` would be overbroad.

Comment: Should the pattern match succeed if `$Mail` ends with `".com\n"`? Also, do you realize that `.` is special in a regex pattern?

Comment: Among the problems Sinan notes, I advise against the end of line anchor, `$`, since that can now change behavior with default regex flags. Use the `\z` if you want end-of-string.